# Trying to populate an array from a text file

Tags: arrays, xcode, uitableview

I'm using xcode, swift 5.0.

I have a multidimensional array for a tableViewController to give a list with different sections.

I would like for the array to be taken from a text file which is stored remotely (so that the array contents can be updated without an app update).

Any advice on how to code for this?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37599632/swift-read-write-array-of-arrays-to-from-file

Comment: check this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723653/turning-json-file-into-an-array-in-swift-xcode